# Script text not working in birt frameset

Tags: birt

I am currently working to make a server side pagination in BIRT report.
For that I have embed my own html buttons and a scripts where on onclick event ,the script gets called and it reload the page with the required parameters so that query can be filtered.

But strangely my script text works in the preview mode but when i switch it to frameset   It simply stops working and I am not able to reach my script on onclick event of my button

Thanks

Comment: When you say "stops working" could you be more specific? Is nothing sent to the server? Is the Javascript executed in the client? What does the script look like? --- We can't read your mind nor see your code.

Comment: Sorry Bob for not being specific. :)

Comment: I have a javascript method which I included as a text in the report. In that very text I have a script tag and two buttons.I have written on-click events on both bottons and on onclick it hits the function in the javascript. Now the problem is that everythings works well till the preview mode is on but when swiched to frameset ,onclick doesnt work at all.It never call the javascript function.

Comment: So the javascript on the client side is not working? Is that correct? I recommend that you use Firebug or the Chrome debugger (preferably the latter) to inspect your page sources, including the frameset contents. Inspect the source code and set some breakpoints. If necessary, attach `alert()` calls to the buttons to check the click functionality.

Comment: Bob I checked the issue with multiple browsers and to my surprise found that the same script is working very well in chrome.Following are the test result with different browsers.

Browser     result
Chrome      Script working both in preview and frameset
Firefox     Script working in preview mode but not in frameset
IE          Birt report itself not working

Comment: Following below is one sample of my script which i have attached in the report.<script>
function nextData(a){
alert(a);

}

</script>

<input type="button" value="Previous"
onclick="nextData('first')" >
<input type="button" value="Next"
onclick="nextData('second')" >

Comment: Each browser handles clicks slightly differently. There are a couple of web sites that provide detailed comparisons of IE handling of various events. They will give you insight into what has to be done to make it work.